# How should I respond with different status codes to a GET request in Spray?

Tags: spray

For POST and PUT requests I use the following syntax:

```
put {
  entity(as[CaseClass]) { entity =>
     returnsOption(entity).map(result => complete{(Created, result)})
       .getOrElse(complete{(NotFound, "I couldn't find the parent resource you're modifying")})
  }
}
```

Now for GET requests I'm trying to do the same, but I can't get it to work analogously to my PUT solution. What is a good way to do this with GET requests?

Update:
I've got this working with the following hack:

```
(get & parameters('ignored.?)) {
  //TODO find a way to do this without ignored parameters
  (ingored:Option[String]) => {
     returnsOption().map(result => complete(result))
       .getOrElse(complete{(NotFound, "")})
  }
 }
```

I'd expect something similar to be possible with `() =>` or `ctx =>` , but that doesn't fly,  because it gives trouble with marshalling:

```
... could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller[(spray.http.StatusCodes.ClientError, String)]
    }).getOrElse(ctx.complete{(NotFound, "")})
                             ^
```

Could it be that this somehow relates to the fact that I'm using spray-json?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code should work:

```
get {
  ctx =>  
     ctx.complete(returnsOption())
 }
```

If don't use `ctx =>` at the start, your code might only be executed at route build time.

Here you can find some explanations: [Understanding the DSL Structure](http://spray.io/documentation/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/)

Comment: That works, but I want to return a different StatusCode based on wether the Option is defined. If you map the option to complete it gets executed once only on startup, which is not my intent.

Comment: That's exactly why you should read the above documentation on the topic. The important thing is to understand that only the code inside of the block started with `ctx =>` is guranteed to be executed on each request and other code may be executed only (which sometimes may be at request handling time but not necessarily) during route _building_ time.

Comment: @jrudolph I understand that, I'll edit the question to reflect that part. Now if the code would return a different status code based on the content of the option, it would totally answer the question.

Comment: get {
  ctx =>  
     returnsOption().map(result => ctx.complete(result))
       .getOrElse(ctx.complete{(NotFound, "")})
 }

Comment: your last example works fine. In my case it wasn't working because of a marshaller problem, unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 15):

Use *[HttpResponse](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/HttpMessage.scala#L225)* like this for example

```
complete{
  HttpResponse(StatusCodes.OK, HttpBody(ContentType(`text/html`), "test test: " + System.currentTimeMillis.toString))
}
```

**Update:** I've been using Spray for a while now. Turned out there is better way:

```
complete {
  StatusCodes.BandwidthLimitExceeded -> MyCustomObject("blah blah")
}
```

Comment: Is there a more concise way to write this?

Comment: @Phil Thank you for reminding me about this question. Yes, there is better way. I updated the answer.